# Java generics- Need to generalize A.class in Object mapper

Tags: java

I have a method which maps `JSON` to Java class.

```
mapper.readValue(messageQueue, MessageQueue.class);
```

I need to use generics such that I can pass classname in method call so that the parsing method can be made generic rather than tighlty coupled. Something like maybe:

```
mapper.readValue(messageQueue, Class<T>.class);
```

Comment: The question is unclear - why do you need generics instead of just passing in a class-name? What would "using generics" look like? Where does the object mapper code come from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: say i have a class A which needs to be mapped  for the string  now i want  to use the same method to map it another class say B.    eg.  return mapper.readValue(messageQueue, MessageQueue.class);  now i want it  to map Class B .but due to hardcoding i would have to create another method.

Comment: just Class<T> cls should work

Comment: I still do not know what `readValue` is supposed to return. Fixing the signature of `readValue` seems easy; fixing `readValue` itself, not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
public <T> T deserialize(String message, Class<T> tClass) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(message, tClass);

}
```